# AddToAny not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, share

I'm trying to use AddToAny to get social media sharing on my website, but it looks like FireFox is blocking it, due to tracking prevention.

Console Message:

```
The resource at “https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js” was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.
```

Is there a way to prevent tracking? My code is very basic:

```
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style" data-a2a-icon-color="transparent,#8d8d8d">
    <a class="a2a_button_facebook mar-r-5"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_twitter mar-r-5"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_email mar-r-5"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
  </div>
  <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
  <!-- AddToAny END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was because I was using the private mode in the FireFox browser!

Comment: [**Beginning at Firefox 63**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-tracking-protection) AddToAny blocked by default for Firefox users. See [**my issue**](https://github.com/mozilla-services/shavar-prod-lists/issues/51) about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to not include their scripts by default. This should improve your page performance.

I’ve just written an article on the new native [Web Share API where AddToAny is used as a fallback.](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/addtoany-web-share.html) In this implementation, scripts from AddToAny isn’t loaded on the page and they’re incapable of tracking the user before the user clicks on a button that opens a new window to AddToAny. This method won’t be blocked by Firefox (or other trackers) as AddToAny is only loaded as a first-party page.